# How to autowire an implementation in an injection point whose type is an interface

Tags: java, spring, interface, dependency-injection

Using Spring MVC, I have this Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;
    // more code and a setter to loginService
}
```

`LoginService` is an interface, whose only implementation is `LoginServiceImpl`:

```
public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService {
    //
}
```

My `project-name-servlet.xml` file is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">   
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="loginService" class="my.example.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl" />
    <bean class="my.example.controller.LoginController" />
</beans>
```

The problem is, `loginService` is not injected into the controller. If I specify the injection in the XML file as below, it works:

```
    <bean id="loginService"
        class="may.example.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl" />
    <bean class="my.example.controller.LoginController">
        <property name="loginService" ref="loginService"></property>
    </bean>
```

Why does this happen? Shouldn't the only implementing bean be injected in an interface-typed injection point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a [AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) for the Autowiring to work - It is byType by default, so you don't have to do anything explicit to inject your loginService into your LoginController. Like the link says, you can put a `<context:annotation-config/>` or `<context:component-scan/>` to automatically register a AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I will try to answer more of my own questions if it yields such excellent answers as well :) Just a note: once I added `<context:component-scan/>`, I had to remove `<bean class="my.example.controller.LoginController" />`.  Otherwise, I get an error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot map handler 'my.example.controller.LoginController#0' to URL path [/login]: There is already handler of type [class my.example.controller.LoginController] mapped.`

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked to me was to define the autowire type as [`byType`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire):

```
    <bean id="loginService"
        class="my.example.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl"
            autowire="byType" />
    <bean class="my.example.controller.LoginController"
            autowire="byType" />
```

Also, I removed the `@Autowired` annotations.